# Using sklearn load_files() to load images from png as data

Tags: python, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm currently using sklearn to build a simple image recogniser.

I need to use load_files('./directory/') to load images from sub-folders within that directory.

It correctly gets the target values but the data attributes are not simple pixel values. I assume I need to set the encoding parameter to consider the image files but can't find what exactly to use.

Answer (score 4):

The encoding parameter is used to decode the raw bytes of the content of the files assuming a text encoding (e.g. UTF-8).

For image files you will need to iterate the content of the `filenames` attribute yourself and use something like [scipy.misc.imread](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imread.html) (you will also need to install PIL or Pillow package).

Here is a utility function to load the data of jpeg files from the Labeled Faces in the Wild as numpy arrays:

https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/datasets/lfw.py#L108

You can use it to understand how to write your own custom dataset loader.